# C# PictureBox clean up and proper zoom

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to clean the `PictureBox` in my Windows Form App before placing an image after it's been interpolated. I've searched for similar situations, but stuff like:

```
pictureBox1.Image=null;
pictureBox1.InitialImage=null;
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
pictureBox1.Dispose();
```

don't work in any combination. I used this method to open the image and put it on the `PictureBox`:

```
void openImage()
{
    DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        file = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = file;
        opened = true;
    }
}
```

After that the image is interpolated with `HighQualityBicubic`, but the outcome is being placed on top of the original image. I used the `Zoom` property of `PictureBox`, so it won't crop the image or cover up the rest of the form.

Is there any way to remove the original picture and enlarge the outcome in the box?

Interpolation method (the guilty part of the code):
void bicubic(int newHeight,int newWidth)
        {

```
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(file);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
       //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
    }
```

Comment: To show a picture in `PictureBox`, it's enough to assign it to its `Image` property.

Comment: That I know, but it's being shrunk and when it's displayed it takes 1/100th of the space in the PictureBox. I want it enlarged/stretched to the size of the PictureBox

Comment: That's what `SizeMode` will do for you.

Comment: You can set SizeMode = ...Zoom before displaying the Image. It will still be interpolated. Not sure what your actual issue is.. - _but the outcome is being placed on top of the original image._ No it isn't!

Comment: InitialImage is only for to brigde the time while the real image loads, btw. Today hardly ever useful..

Comment: The bug is located in the "interpolated with HighQualityBicubic* part of the code.  We can't see it.

Comment: Yes, after some testing it seems that it creates the image composed of both the original image and the outcome of interpolation. I added the method to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a image with out come size. In your code you are creating the new image with original image size

```
        Bitmap OrgImage = new Bitmap(file);
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(OrgImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
```

this may solve your problem

Comment: It probably does, but gr.Clear() might be necessary to avoid unintentional transparency effects.

Answer (score 0):

`PictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage` will stretch the image for you.

If you want other Sizing properties, just scroll trough the **PictureBoxSizeMode** enum.

As for reassignment, setting the `PictureBox`'s `Image` property to `null` should be enough

Comment: SizeMode propably will do the trick, but sadly setting Image to null doesn't help

Comment: Have you also tried setting the `InitialImage` property to null aswell? Also, `pictureBox1.Image.Dispose()`?

Comment: I did. Also the Invalidate  method

Comment: In your code I see `pictureBox1.Dispose()`, not `pictureBox1.Image.Dispose()`. Please note that not Disposing an image and just setting it to null, will cause the object to rest in your memory.

Comment: pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = null;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
Streched nicely, but didn't remove the image

Comment: Try assigning the image to a variable instead of assigning it directly the control.